# How to rename the same value in a column using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe is :
[image]

How can I display rows with the same data in the hospital column in this way via pandas?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way:

```
df['hospital'] += '_' + df.groupby('hospital').cumcount().add(1).map(str)
```

Comment: this way also data where there is only one row will get "_1" als suffix. Is there a way to only apply this to data where groupby is at least of length 2 ?

Answer (score 1):

You can groupby Hospital and transform a function that counts the number of hospitals in each group and adds a cumulative index if that number exceeds 1 and adds nothing if its a singleton:

```
df['Hospital'] = df['Hospital'] + df.groupby('Hospital')['Hospital'].transform(lambda x: '_' + (x==x).cumsum().astype(str) if len(x)>1 else '')
```

Output:

```
                           Hospital
0               UCLA Medical Center
1           Massachusetts General_1
2           Massachusetts General_2
3  Northwestern Memorial Hospital_1
4  Northwestern Memorial Hospital_2
5  Northwestern Memorial Hospital_3
6              Mount Sinai Hospital
```

Comment: ，Moving on from this question, what if I want to implement adding _1, _2 after the hospital only when the GeneralRepresentation of the same hospital corresponds to a different person's name? How should I do this?

Comment: @Andrew One way would be to use .drop_duplicates() to drop all rows which contain both the same general representation and name.

Comment: thanks @Manlai. I want to understand what is happening here but by debugging I can't get it . So I have two questions: 1) why we need `(x==x).cumsum()` instead of just `x.cumsum()` ? 2) why does transform - which performs line by line in my understanding - see the `x` in ´len(x)>1` as the groupby instead of the value in that line? I guess question 1 and 2 are connected but I can't figure it out..